# Convert Eclipse project files between versions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have various Eclipse CDT projects, spanning different versions of Eclipse. Usually it seems trivial to import the projects into a new workspace - if the version of Eclipse is later than the version used to create the project. However, I occasionally need to go backwards in versions, which completely screws with the build configurations that are defined.

Does anyone know if there is a utility available to convert .project and .cproject files backwards? Primarily I'm interested in going from Indigo to Helios, but flexibility to go between many different versions would be great.

Thanks,

-D